# When using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Entity Framework to do an initial migration, I get an error "The entity type 'X' requires a primary key to be defined"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, key

When using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Entity Framework to do an initial migration, I get an error "The entity type 'X' requires a primary key to be defined".

```
public class Command
{
    [Key]
    private int _id;
    public int CommandId { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
    public string HowTo { get; set; }
    public string Line { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use [NotMapped] Instead of [Key] above your _id.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just **guessing** - but I think you want to use the `CommandId` as key - right??

If so, then you need to decorate that property with the =`[Key]` annotation - like this:

```
public class Command
{
    private int _id;

    [Key]
    public int CommandId { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }

    public string HowTo { get; set; }
    public string Line { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
}
```

Or just leave that annotation off - a property called `Id` or `(EntityName)Id` will be automatically used as the primary key - and `CommandId` matches this second pattern for an automatically recognized primary key property.

Comment: Hi @marc_s,Why did I use the same code as op and then I successfully migrated?The CommandId will be automatically set as primary key.

Comment: @Yinqiu: the `CommandId` will be used automatically **UNLESS** you set the `[Key]` elsewhere - and setting it on a private field **does not work**

Comment: After running: dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration   I get: The entity type 'Command' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.